# How to iterate through a table in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a script to compare the records in a database in my DynamoDB with record in another database in EC2. 
I will appreciate any help with iterating through the table in Python.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tried :

my_table = db_conn.get_table('[table name]') 
                

        my_item = my_table.scan("sg-734cef17", attributes_to_get=['resource_id'])

At this point I can get an item but I have to specify one. What I need is to get items withought need to specifying.

Comment: You have to loop through the resultset. Have a look at this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same need when I query DynamoDB from an AWS Lambda in Python and expected the dataset to be over 128MB of memory limit. If I can't iterate through, I'll have to pay extra bucks to AWS. Unfortunately, it seems there is no way to do so except converting the query response to an iterator (which wouldn't save memory at all).